# Show that the intersections of the $G_s$ is normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

I need to prove that given a  group $G$ acting in a set $S$, the intersection of the stabilizers $G_s$, where $G_s:=\{g\in G: g.s=s\}$ and $s$ varies through all $S$, is a normal subgroup of $G$.

But the thing is to find the right homomorphism, or is there an easier way to do it?, Can you help me to prove this result please? Thank you.

Comment: Just show directly that $\left(\bigcap_{s\in S}G_s\right)^a=G$ for each $a\in G$; it’s a pretty straightforward calculation.

Comment: Thank you @BrianM.Scott  but I dont undestand this idea ?

Comment: A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $H^a=H$ for each $a\in G$, where $H^a=a^{-1}Ha$.

Comment: Ok I got The idea :).

Comment: Can you help me with the homomorphism please?

Comment: You don’t need a homomorphism!

Comment: Yes but How could this prove be completed with an homomorphism ?

Comment: Like an alternative proof :)

Comment: I don’t see an obvious way to do that. It certainly seems a hard way to approach the problem.

Comment: Ok thank you a lot @BrianM.Scott :)

Comment: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G_a$ be the stabilizer of $a$. It is easy to see $gG_ag^{-1}$ is a subgroup of the stabilizer of $ga$ (In fact they are equal but you don't need this).

So any conjugate of a stabilizer is a subgroup of another stabilizer, thus the image of the intersection of all stabilizers under conjugation by $g$  is a subgroup of the intersection of all stabilizers, in other words the intersection of the stabilizers is normal.

Comment: Which the conjugate of a stabilizer ?

Comment: I meant any conjugate, the conjugate by $g$ of the set $A$ is the set $gAg^{-1}$

Comment: Ok I understand :), and can I say it like that? because of the formality :)

Comment: I think you can say it like that, if you have any trouble with the grades you can tell me about it and I'll help you argue why it's correct, althoug the most important thing is YOU understand it.

Comment: Good thank you a lot @JorgeFernadez :) and I dont have to prove some of the things you use in the proof isnt?

Answer (score 1):

One can also do the following: The definition of a group operation implies that the map

$$
\Phi : G \to {\rm Sym}_S, g \mapsto \phi_g
$$

with $\phi_g (s) = g.s$ is a homomorphism, where ${\rm Sym}(S)$ is the group of all bijections of $S$.

It is easy to check that

$$
\bigcap_s G_s = {\rm Ker}(\Phi),
$$
and hence normal.